# jquery mobile collapse if mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have a web application built on JQuery Mobile.
I've been looking for a way to have certain divs (which have data-role="collapsible") be collapsed when viewed on a mobile device, but expanded if viewed on a desktop browser.

I know there are a lot of similar questions, but I haven't been able to get any of those solutions to work. Here's what I've tried.

The divs have a class of mobileHide

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
/*collapse non-crucial sections when viewed on mobile device*/
/* this works while resizing desktop browser, but can't resize mobile browser*/
$(window).on('resize', function(){
var w = $(window).width();
if(w >= 540 ) {
    $( ".mobileHide" ).trigger( "expand" );
}else{
    $( ".mobileHide" ).trigger( "collapse" );
}
});

/* Tried setting @media to make .hide-element {display:none} if screen size less than 540px (which worked in hiding that element) then set is_mobile to true. Also tried doing the same without the is_mobile and just using "if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) )"*/
$(window).resize(function() {
var is_mobile = false;

if( $('.hide-element').css('display')=='none' {
    is_mobile = true;       
}

if(!is_mobile) {
$( ".mobileHide" ).trigger( "expand" );
}else{
$( ".mobileHide" ).trigger( "collapse" );
}
});

/*Also tried this without being in a window.resize function. The alert works when viewed on mobile device, but the collapse and expand don't*/
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
  /*alert("I am mobile!");*/
  $( ".mobileHide" ).trigger( "collapse" );
} else {
 $( ".mobileHide" ).trigger( "expand" );
}
</script>
```

I didn't have all of those running at once, but each piece that I commented on was the only part that was active at the time.

Any insight into why the last one detects mobile device and displays the alert (when it's not commented out) but won't trigger the collapse when it detects mobile device would be much appreciated!

Comment: Which version of jQM?

Comment: try --  $( ".mobileHide" ).children().trigger( "collapse" );    --- and to expand --- and use the javascript way to detect as you getting alerts --- if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {

Comment: For 1.4.x: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/suPc7/, for 1.3: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/suPc7/1/. Working demos using window width

Comment: Hey sorry for delay, I didn't refresh the page so I didn't see the reply (doh!).
It's version 1.0... I started to update it in the past, but I have so much built on it already and too many things stopped working correctly I just decided to stick with 1.0 until I'm ready to do a complete rebuild (after this version is out there doing its job).

Comment: Thanks all.
@ezanker, I used the code from your 1.3 jsfiddle and it works! Thanks! 
I don't see an option to mark it as the correct answer, does it need to be listed as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: I have added it as an answer so you can accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/suPc7/1/)**

The function `CollapsiblesOnSize()` checks the window width and then either collapses or expands all elements with class of `mobileHide`. You can then call this on window resize, orientation change and jQM's pageshow:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#page1", function () {
    CollapsiblesOnSize();
    $(window).on("resize orientationchange", function(){
        CollapsiblesOnSize();
    });
});

function CollapsiblesOnSize(){
    var w = $(window).width();
    if(w >= 540 ) {
        $( ".mobileHide" ).trigger( "expand" );
    }else{
        $( ".mobileHide" ).trigger( "collapse" );
    }
}
```